# Git Bash on Windows - CMake Error: The source directory does not exists

Tags: cmake

I use Git Bash on Windows 10. When I run the following command from the `TestCpp` directory:

```
cmake -S . -B build -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A "Win32"
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Projects/TestCpp/build" does not exist.
```

When I create a build folder and then run the command from that folder:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A "Win32" ..
```

everything works fine. Why the first command doesn't work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior described exists when trying to use the -S and -B options with an older version of CMake that does not support them. Support for these options is [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) as starting in 3.13.

Comment: [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) states that when use `-S` and `-B` options, the build directory should be automatically created by CMake: "The build tree will be created automatically if it does not already exist." Also it is suspicious "source" word in the error message: Would CMake mean a build tree, the error message would be "The **build** directory "C:/Projects/TestCpp/build" does not exist."

Comment: @Tsyvarev that is correct. It looks like the actual issue was the version of CMake being used. I can replicate the error message "CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Projects/TestCpp/build" does not exist." when using Cmake 3.4 and it is likely the same for all versions below 3.13 when -S and -B were added to the documentation.

Comment: Yes, too low CMake version could be the very reason. BTW, no one forces you to edit your answer by **appending** the "edit" clause. Unlike to many other forums, on Stack Overflow we expect the answer to contain **actual** information. That is, if you find words about non-existed build directory are no longer be true, you could completely remove them from the answer. Or, you could move them to the **end** of the post, after the **real** answer. No needs to reflect a history of your answer post in the answer itself: Anyone who curious about the history can find it below the post.